# Using an assembly that references a second assembly, without referencing that assembly

Tags: c#

I have a small library I've written of various random extension methods. Recently I rolled a few WPF `FrameworkElement` extension methods into it, but found myself getting compiler errors in another project (console application) that used my library because now it wanted references to several WPF related assemblies (cannot find FrameworkElement, etc etc). This project doesn't call any of the methods that involve `FrameworkElement`.

As my extension method library grows, I'd prefer that I didn't have to break it into several small assemblies, nor do I want to add a bunch of references to WPF assemblies in non-WPF projects. Is there a way to handle this, or am I just going to have to break up my library?

I'm using VS 2013 with .NET 4.5

Comment: Which version of VS are you using? Less relevant, which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: @Eric VS 2013 and .NET 4.5

Comment: why don't you write a separate assembly for WPF stuff? It's better to separate things: you don't need to load too much into memory for unnecessary things,..

Comment: Just a guess here, are you targeting the same Framework with both projects? I also remember that there is a setting to forward dependencies, but it was for C++ I think.

Comment: @KhanhTO When I started this library, it was originally broken into two pieces, but then I got worried that it would grow and I would eventually have to add half a dozen `using` statements to any code file that I wanted to use all the extension methods for. It's also used by some coworkers of mine and I'd hoped to take out the guessing of which assembly they need to reference by having only one.

Comment: @Eric Yes, all the projects are .NET 4.5

Comment: You may want to try moving all methods in the library that have dependencies on `FrameworkElement` into another class that the console project does not use, however I don't think there are any options other than the ones you have mentioned. In general, if you have a library, taking on a dependency or exposing a public member with a dependency on an external type is a huge concern that is not to be taken lightly.

Comment: Adding `using` statements is good because it indicates `clearly` what you want to import to your project. In your case, when the assembly grows, the projects referencing the assembly will import things they `don't expect automatically`.

Comment: @KhanhTO When you say it will import things that aren't expected, do you mean having lots of extension methods that aren't relevant to a project?

Comment: Side note: there is no correlation between assembly and name spaces. If you really want you can have all your classes to be in own assemblies, but all have the same namespace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out you can do this by putting the offending types in a different namespace. All of my extension methods were in the same `Common.Extensions` namespace, which apparently causes everything in that namespace to be loaded. By moving the WPF specific extensions to `Common.WPF.Extensions` I was able to keep them all in the same assembly.

**Update:**

The specific cause for this error came down to public facing types that were included in one of the extension methods. Turns out you CAN have an extension method for a type that you don't have a reference for, but none of those methods can have an argument, a return, or a type declaration that uses the un-referenced type. In my case I had

```
public static void SetParentCursor<T>(this FrameworkElement frameworkElement, Cursor cursor) where T : FrameworkElement
```

The `where T : FrameworkElement` is what killed it in the end.